# Strange cakePHP Auth issue for IE (login not working)

Tags: internet-explorer, cakephp-1.3

I am facing a strange issue here.

I am using CakePHP 1.3.6 & for IE 6-7-8 it is not allowing me to login. I am using the correct credentials. tested these with recorded in logs.

There is no any auth error displayed. (If i use wrong credentials then it shows the auth error, but for correct credentials it shows nothing :( )

I have tested all the possibility with auth component by logging logs into the error.log file.

I checked the Auth->user method. It populates Auth session, but even though it is not redirecting me to the desired location. 
I also checked the authLoginurl : it is aslo correct in logs.

I have checked the following possibilities,

1) Changed some settings from Core.php

-- Session.checkAgent set to false
  -- Security.level set to low
  -- Session.start set to false

2) used disableCache() for login action to avoid the caching of the login data in browser.

3) After logout i have destroyed the session.

Here is the code,

App Controller in beforeFilter :

$this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');

```
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'myaccount');

    $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.is_active' => '1', 'User.is_verified' => '1');

    //$this->referer();
    //auth errors  //add it
    $this->Auth->loginError = "Invalid username or password";
    $this->Auth->authError = "Sorry, you must be logged in to visit these pages";

    //logout
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
```

User Controller beforeFilter() :

function beforeFilter() {

```
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Auth->allow(allowed_actions);
```

}

Thnaks,
Vijay

Comment: It's implied, but not stated, that logging in works in other browsers but not IE.  Is this correct?

Comment: You mean to say login. Yes Login works in other browser but not in IE. Its Login not Logging.  Sorry if any confusion there.

Comment: Logging in means the same thing :)

Comment: hmm... but actually It is not redirecting me to the AuthLoginurl path... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had the same problem, it was with a different cake version, but maybe this solution will help.

In config I made a `my_session.php` file with the following values:

```
ini_restore('session.referer_check');
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);
ini_set('session.name', Configure::read('Session.cookie'));
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
// Cookie path is now '/' even if you app is within a sub 
// directory on the domain
$this->path = '/';
ini_set('session.cookie_path', $this->path);
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', env('HTTP_BASE'));
```

The important part is the `$this->path` value, sessions are now available for the whole domain.

In `core.php` for sessions add:

```
Configure::write('Session.save', 'my_session');
```

Hopes this helps!

Comment: This hasn't solved the issue in my case, it is working perfect in chrome and firefox but not in IE and opera. This line returns null in IE and opera: debug($this->Auth->user('name'));

I am using cake php 2.3.5 and have tested it on IE 8 & 10